# Return by const reference in c++ where the receiver function copy the value is it worth it?

Tags: c++, const-reference

i have this situation which i wander if returning by const reference dose relay save something , this function may be called hundreds  of times .

i have :
General Container that returns int as const reference

```
struct Val
{
 public:
    Val(int& v)
    {
        iVal = v;
    }

    const int& toInt()
    {
        return iVal;
    }

private:
    int iVal;
};
```

function that getting the number:

```
Val Mo::doSomthing()
{
  Val v(444444);
  return v;
}
```

calling the d`oSomthing().toInt()`:

```
int x = 0;
class Foo {
...
....
Mo mo;
void Foo::setInt(float scaleX)
{

   x = mo.doSomthing().toInt();
   //x is class member which other functions are using it 

}
...
...
..
}
```

In this case is there any reason to for using const reference to save some bits?

Comment: Returning fundamental types by reference is kind of unnecessary overhead. Two copies may in fact be cheaper than a single copy and a const reference. Only way to know for sure however, is to profile your tight loop.

Comment: Read up on premature optimization. In general, **measure**.

Comment: First question: How many billions of times will this loop execute in a typical hour of program operation? If the answer isn't "more than one" then you're wasting time here. These sorts of operations are stupidly fast on modern processors. If you're benchmarking it don't be surprised if you need to run more than a few million cycles to get any meaningful data.

Comment: Voted to close as primarily opinion based, although the main problem is that the question is based on invalid assumptions: the incorrect "save some bits", and the incorrect idea that the effect would be largely system-independent, and the incorrect assumption that premature optimization is a good idea.

Comment: The main reason for returning something by const reference is if you need to return a expensive member from inside the class without allowing the caller write access and thus breaking encapsulation. A example would be std::string::c_str().

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  
this is the link?
http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @user63898: It seems to be a nice discussion about premature optimization. It's a difficult topic because deciding in a good way what's premature or not, and whether one should invest time on measuring, etc., depends on context, knowledge and intelligence, and maybe more. The Knuth quote is classic, but he in turn attributed it to someone else, IIRC. [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) is often a good place to start. About anything. :)

Comment: For a general purpose container I think it isn't a premature optimization but a big decision with deep impact.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  Thanks, i have so many questions on the subject for example , if i have only 1 element in vector should i always check if vector size is 1 to avoid looping it ? and return the first element ? 
when 90% of times i only receive only 1 element ?

Comment: @Broothy: You're right (IMO). For example, the proposed string view returns by reference, thereby preventing its use to access a future ref-counted string; in effect preventing some standard changes for the better by more deeply entrenching current limitations. It's very much politics, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for scalar types it is cheaper to return them by value. A reference (and a pointer) has near the same size (word length) as an usual scalar type. If you return an int& you return ~the same amount of data, however when you access the data referenced the running platform has to resolve the reference (access the memory referenced).

But the previous comments are right: measure it first. It is a kind of micro optimization.

Comment: Instead of "POD type" you should have said "builtin type".

Comment: You're absolutely right, in my mind PODs are the builtin types and the very small structs but the definition of POD types is more wider. I corrected my answer.